# How to Capture Fingerprint on Android web browser?

Tags: capture, fingerprint, fingerprinting

I’m using Secugen HU20 fingerprint scanner.
I have a web application where I need to capture the fingerprints of the users, I have installed the web API of secugen and successfully capture the fingerprints, but I need to use it on mobile also where I'm getting error, that's because I could not install the web API of secugen on my android.
Can you help me how to use web API on mobile.

can anyone please tell me how to capture fingerprint from the web application on android phones.

Here I’m using the following APIs endpoint,

https://localhost:8443/SGIFPCapture

website link here:
https://secugen.com/drivers/

I'm using web api of secugen to capture the fingerprints